# Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

Tags: flutter

In qr_code_scanner for flutter, I am getting this error that I dont know how to fix

```
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.0.14\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (41, 77): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onActivityPaused(@nonnull p0: Activity): Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.0.14\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (42, 13): 'onActivityPaused' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.0.14\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (48, 13): 'onActivityResumed' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.0.14\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (54, 13): 'onActivityStarted' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.0.14\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (57, 13): 'onActivityDestroyed' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.0.14\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (60, 13): 'onActivitySaveInstanceState' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.0.14\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (63, 13): 'onActivityStopped' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-0.0.14\android\src\main\kotlin\net\touchcapture\qr\flutterqr\QRView.kt: (66, 13): 'onActivityCreated' overrides nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see if I were to change the code to be like

```
override fun onActivityResumed(p0: Activity) {
    if (p0 == registrar.activity()) {
        barcodeView?.resume()
    }
}

override fun onActivityStarted(p0: Activity) {
}

override fun onActivityDestroyed(p0: Activity) {
}

override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle) {
}

override fun onActivityStopped(p0: Activity) {
}

override fun onActivityCreated(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle?) {
}
```

it would work fine. I dont know kotlin but I tried my best to implement the abstract class as it should be. Should I create a PR for that or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I have created a PR and it got merged https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner/pull/167 so hopefully in the next 2 days or so we will find a new release of that package with the fix.